# The same operator is used even after choosing a different one

Tags: python, python-2.x

The code uses operator that was chosen in the previous play even after choosing a different operator after opting to play again.

I've checked the functions again and still can't find where exactly the problem is.

```
import random

print "Welcome!"

def get_choice():
    print "What are we practicing? \n1. Addition (+) \n2. Subtraction (-) \n3. Multiplication (*) \n4. Division (/)"

    option = raw_input('> ')

    while option != '+' and option != '-' and option != '*' and option != '/':
        print "You typed %r which is not valid. Please enter \'+, -, *,or /\'" %(option)
        option = raw_input('>')
    return option

operation = get_choice()

def ask_question (operation):
    numbers = []
    for y in range(0,2):
        x = random.randint(1,100)
        numbers.append(x)
    num1 = numbers[0]
    num2 = numbers[1]
    print num1, operation, num2
    response = int(raw_input('>'))
    return num1, num2, response

num1, num2, response = ask_question(operation)

def check_response(response):
    if operation == '+':
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operation == '-':
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operation == '*':
        answer = num1 * num2
    else:
        answer = num1 / num2

    i = 0
    if response == answer:
        print "Correct!"
    elif response != answer:
        while i < 2:
            print "Wrong! Try again: \n%r + %r" %(num1, num2)
            i += 1
            response = raw_input()
            if response != answer and i >= 2:
                print "Sorry. You run out of chances."

check_response(response)

def repeat():
    while True:
        print "Do you want to play again?"
        again = raw_input('>')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            get_choice()
            ask_question(operation)
            check_response(response)
        else:
            break   
repeat()
```

> Welcome! What are we practicing?
>
> 1. Addition (+)
> 2. Subtraction (-)
> 3. Multiplication (*)
> 4. Division (/)
>
>      *
>
> 18 * 4
>
> 72 Correct! Do you want to play again?
>
> y
>
> > What are we practicing?
>
> 1. Addition (+)
> 2. Subtraction (-)
> 3. Multiplication (*)
> 4. Division (/)
>
> > +
> >
> > 94 * 83

Comment: The first time you call `get_option()` you assign the result to the global variable `operation`. When you call it again, you ignore the return value. You also ignore the return value of `ask_question`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gets stuck on one operation is you are not catching any return value from `get_choice()` when you call it within `repeat()`. I adjusted the `raw_input()` to `input()` so I could get it to work (I'm on python 3.X, and you should upgrade also since 2.X will be discontinued this year!), and it seems to work fine for me now:

```
def repeat():
    while True:
        print("Do you want to play again?")
        again = input('>')
        if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            operation = get_choice() # you need to assign "operator" to the return value
            ask_question(operation)
            check_response(response)
        else:
            break
repeat()
```

Sample output:

```
Welcome!
What are we practicing? 
1. Addition (+) 
2. Subtraction (-) 
3. Multiplication (*) 
4. Division (/)
> +
82 + 72
>154
Correct!
Do you want to play again?
>y
What are we practicing? 
1. Addition (+) 
2. Subtraction (-) 
3. Multiplication (*) 
4. Division (/)
> -
57 - 28 # the sign did in fact change to -
>
```